# The sum of $q^{-2}$ over nonzero Gaussian integers

Tags: nt.number-theory, cv.complex-variables, analytic-number-theory, lattices, periodic-functions

I'm reading about the Weierstrass zeta function. In this context,
$\phi(z)=\zeta(z)-\pi\bar{z}$
is periodic over the lattice
$$\mathcal{L}=\{a+bi\mid a,b\in\mathbb{Z}\}.$$
If we take $w\in\mathcal{L}\setminus\{\mathbf{0}\}$, then
$$\phi(z+w)-\phi(z)=w\sum_{q\in\mathcal{L}\setminus\{0\}}q^{-2}-\pi\bar{w}.$$ Since $\phi$ is periodic, we get
$$\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{q\in\mathcal{L}\setminus\{0\}}q^{-2}=\frac{\bar{w}}{w}.$$
At this point, I wonder the value of this summation. If someone knows about this, please let me know.

**Question.** What is the value of
$$\sum_{q\in\mathcal{L}\setminus\{0\}}q^{-2}?$$

Comment: It seems to me that series does not converge, at least not absolutely, since the number of $q$ with $|q|$ near $R$ is linear in $R$. And I think you demonstrate yourself that it can't be assigned a well-defined value, since your equation is valid for any $w$, and $\frac{\overline{w}}{w}$ takes different values.

Comment: As $\mathcal{L}=i\mathcal{L}$, your sum $S$ formally satisfies $S=i^{-2}S=-S$ giving $S=0$.  This suggests that any attempt to define $S$ by some kind of regularisation will just give $S=0$ unless the regularisation scheme somehow breaks the symmetry.

Comment: @NeilStrickland Your comment resonates with my response (we wrote at the same time).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The series
$$\sum_{q\in\mathcal{L}\setminus\{0\}}q^{-2}$$
is not absolutely convergent. If we arrange the terms in groups of four of shape $\{\pm q,\pm iq\}$, then the series converges to zero since
$$q^{-2}+(iq)^{-2}+(-q)^{-2}+(-iq)^{-2}=0,\qquad q\in\mathcal{L}\setminus\{0\}.$$
For more general sums of similar shape, see [Eisenstein series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein_series).

Comment: To what "term group" does something like the term with index $q=2+3i$ (that is not on a diagonal) belong?

Comment: $\{\pm q, \pm iq\} = \{2+3i, -2-3i, -3+2i,3-2i\}$